# Is there a number $n>2$ that has $n$ factors, including itself

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was wondering if there is any number $n>2$ such that it also has $n$ factors, including itself. Clearly $1$ and $2$ both meet the requirements, which is why I set $n>2$. I came across highly composite numbers on Wikipedia, but I didn't find exactly what I was looking for. If there is no such $n>2$, is there a proof showing why it is not possible?

Comment: n factors implies that the number is at least 2^n

Comment: n=2 has 2 factors but $2<2^2$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  To have $n$ factors every number from $1$ to $n$ would have to divide $n$.  For $n \gt 2, \ n-1$ does not divide $n$.

You might be interested in [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), where $\phi(n)$ is the number of numbers $k$ less than $n$ which are coprime to $n$, that have $\gcd(k,n)=1$.  All of these except $1$ are nonfactors of $n$ but there can be numbers that are neither coprime nor factors.

Comment: Yes, that seems so obvious I do not know why I did not think of that. This is what I've worked out from what you have said: $\frac{n}{n-1} \text{(an integer if n-1|n)}=\frac{n-1+1}{n-1}=1+\frac{1}{n-1} \text{(an integer iff n=2)}$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.